# Remove NavigaionBar In BCTabBar

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

i Tried To Make CustomTabBar With Animation Like BCTabBar

and I write this code in AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.   tabBarController.delegate = self;
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.tabBarController = [[BCTabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                                       initWithRootViewController:[[ProfileViewController alloc] init]],  [[ChargeViewController alloc] init],
                                             [[OffersViewController alloc] init],
                                             [[ContactUsViewController alloc] init],
                                             nil,nil];

    [self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```

and It Works Fine But I wanna Remove NavigationBar In RootViewController What I Can Do ?

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just hide Tabbar?

```
- (void)hideTabBar:(BCTabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
{
    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[BCTabBarController class]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        } 
        else 
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception :S
i Can Hide NavigationBar But My Tab Bar is shifted down 10 pixel   can you help me ?

Comment: [tabBar setFrame:CGRectMake(tabBar.frame.origin.x, tabBar.frame.origin.y - 10, tabBar.frame.size.width, tabBar.frame.size.height)]

Answer (score 0):

In `ProfileViewController` class write `[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];`. That should hide the navigation bar. If you need to show it anywhere else you can again set it as `[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];`